# Import inside an object

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm new at TypeScript and am trying to convert my current JavaScript to TypeScript.

In JS I have constructions like:

```
var roles = {
    x: require('role.x'),
    y: require('role.y')
};
```

With the purpose of later iterating over those roles like this:

```
for (var index in roles) {
  var role = new roles[index];
  if (someObject.role == role.role) {
    role.run(someObject);
  }
}
```

In TypeScript however, It seems I'm not able to do this:

```
let roles = {
  x: import X from "./roles/x"
}
```

Which yields

```
Error:(11, 14) TS1109: Expression expected.
Error:(11, 21) TS1005: ':' expected.
Error:(11, 31) TS1005: ',' expected.
Error:(11, 36) TS1005: ':' expected.
```

So what would be the TypeScript equivalent of achieving the same **-or-** an alternate method that's cleaner/the TypeScript way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not about TypeScript but ES6. Imports are static, they cannot be used dynamically:

```
import * as x from "./roles/x";
import * as y from "./roles/y";
let roles = {
    x: x,
    y: y
};
```

See [a good introduction to ES6 modules here](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/). In the section "Static vs. dynamic":

> For a dynamic language, JavaScript has gotten itself a surprisingly static module system.
>
> - All flavors of `import` and `export` are allowed only at toplevel in a module. There are no conditional imports or exports, and you can’t use import in function scope.
> - All exported identifiers must be explicitly exported by name in the source code. You can’t programmatically loop through an array and export a bunch of names in a data-driven way.

Comment: Although both answers are correct, I'll accept this one for the ES6 modules primer and the definitive `and you can’t use import in function scope.` Thanks!

Comment: No problem, plus, he was first to answer :)

Answer (score 5):

For completeness' sake, now (and since 2017), another way to do this is by using a dynamic import statement.

The [V8 Specs](https://v8.dev/features/dynamic-import) give more information on this.

The `import()` statement returns a promise.

So, in theory, this should work (and look more similar to JS `require` code):

```js
let roles = {
    x: await import('./roles/x'),
    y: await import('./roles/y')
};
```

If you want to assign a particular function/entity from the imported file, you should be able to it thus so:

```
let roles = {
    x: await (async () => {let {X} = await import('./roles/x'); return X;})()
    y: await (async () => {let {Y} = await import('./roles/x'); return Y;})()
};
```

If one is a fan of using `.then()` instead (for concurrency), then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44037727/7778741) StackOverflow answer shows replacement of await by `.then()` to assign the returned promise to an object key.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

ES6 imports must be found at the top level of your module, else it's a syntax error.

```
import * as x from "./roles/x";
import * as y from "./roles/y";

let roles = {x, y};
```