# Async / await assignment to object keys: is it concurrent?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise, ecmascript-2017

I know that doing this:

```
const resultA = await a()
const resultB = await b()
// code here
```

Is effectively

```
a().then( resultA => {
   b().then( resultB => {
      // code here
   })
})
```

Basically, a() runs *then* b() runs. I nested them to show that both resultA and resultB are in our scope; yet both function didn't run at once.

But what about this:

```
const obj = {
  result1: await a(),
  result2: await b()
}
```

do a() and b() run concurrently?

For reference:

```
const asyncFunc = async (func) => await func.call()
const results = [funcA,funcB].map( asyncFunc )
```

I know here `funcA` and `funcB` do run concurrently.

**Bonus**:

How would you represent the object assignment

```
const obj = {
  result1: await a(),
  result2: await b()
}
```

using `then` / callbacks?

---

UPDATE:

@Bergi is correct in this answer, this occurs sequentially. To share a nice solution for having this work concurrently for an object without having to piece together the object from an array, one can also use `Bluebird` as follows

```
const obj2 = Bluebird.props(obj)
```

http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.props.html

Comment: Your "for reference" example has a syntax error (and is misleading because of that). If you use `await`, you have to make the arrow function `async`, and then it becomes obvious that they might run concurrently because they're separate function evaluation.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, corrected.

Comment: Note that the JS functions may trigger asynchronous processes that run concurrently, but the JS functions themselves aren't running concurrently in the sense of multi-threaded simultaneous execution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, every `await` will stop the execution until the promise has fulfilled, even mid-expression. It doesn't matter whether they happen to be part of the same statement or not.

If you want to run them in parallel, and wait only once for their result, you have to use `await Promise.all(…)`. In your case you'd write

```
const [result1, result2] = await Promise.all([a(), b()]);
const obj = {result1, result2};
```

---

> How would you represent the object assignment using `then` / callbacks?

With temporary variables for each awaited value. Every `await` translates into one `then` call:

```
a().then(tmp1 => {
  return b().then(tmp2 => {
    const obj = {
      result1: tmp1,
      result2: tmp2
    };
    return …
  });
})
```

If we wanted to be pedantic, we'd have to pick apart the object creation:

```
const tmp0 = {};
a().then(tmp1 => {
  tmp0.result1 = tmp1;
  return b().then(tmp2 => {
    tmp0.result2 = tmp2;
    const obj = tmp0;
    return …
  });
})
```

Comment: You're right! I just finished writing test code to try the above code using setTimeout and it does indeed run sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

> do a() and b() run concurrently?

No, they run sequentially.

The equivalent would be something like

```
a()
.then(result1 => b())
  .then(result2 => ({result1, result2}))
```